# Why set UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") on field that has attribute: [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

I have document class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Document
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<DataSource> DataSourceList { get; set; }

}
```

this class has a property `DataSourceList` that this is the class:

```
public class DataSource
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

But when I save new `Document` that contains new `DataSource` on the `DataSourceList` property' the GUID that crated automatic is: `UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")`

why is it happening? What can I do to actually have a new GUID automatically generated?

Comment: What driver / version is in use?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods - where can I saw this?

Comment: You tagged "MongoDB", so you probably are using some kind of library for access, right? And that library has a version? Possibly a nuget?

Comment: `BsonId` should not be added for inner fields in the schema. It's a field that should be mapped to `_id` in the db document and should be only in the root

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an idea that works great

Below is the code:

```
public class DataSource
{
    private Guid id;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty)
                id = Guid.NewGuid();
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != Guid.Empty && value != null)
                id = value;
            else
                id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

And it works great!